# How can unordered_map be efficiently implemented with tree data structures?

Tags: c++

Consider `unordered_map`:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

I know `(a==b)` is faster than `!(a<b) && !(b>a)`, but since `unordered_map` does not use `std::less<Key>` to compare/store the keys in the map, I wonder how can an implementation profit by tree data structures in the most efficient way to read/store different keys in the same bucket. It seems that a convertion from Key to a sort of KeyWrapper with `operator<()` defined cannot be avoided by any implementation with trees.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here.  Are you talking about using trees within a bucket?  Or using a tree instead of a hash table?  (This latter case is what a std::map is.)  But your general question: for any kind of efficient tree, you need a comparison operator to properly balance the tree.

Comment: yes, I am talking about trees within a bucket (i.e. splay trees)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a tree inside `unordered_map`, even just within a bucket. `unordered_map`'s interface simply does not allow it. The key type is required only to be equality comparable, nothing more. That's why it's called an "unordered" map; because there is no specific ordering of elements. To use some kind of binary tree would require a strict weak ordering, which is not required.

If you want to use a variation of an `unordered_map`, you may. But it would not be an `unordered_map` as defined by the standard.

Comment: I was talking about trees for storing/reading elements collapsing in the same bucket